# How to append a directory to the existing variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script which runs and creates directory. My folder structure is as shown below:

```
--Top folder
    -- Folder A
    -- Folder B
```

Now the shell script current directory is the path to top folder. Now i want to send the path of Folder A to my python script and also the Top folder path.
So in the shell script i assign a variable to the current path and send it to the script. But This folder A is not created by shell script but already exist. this is my shell script code:

**my_script.sh**

```
 DIR=$(pwd)
/build/test_report.py "$DIR" #call with a argument. How to send second argument?
```

Comment: is your python script able to handle multiple arguments ? if so, simply call `/build/test_report.py "$DIR" "/other/path" "/yet/something/else"`

Comment: Why do you write a bash script to call a python script? why don't you write everything in python? or in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can append the child directory name to the current dir.

```
DIR=$(pwd)
/build/test_report.py "$DIR" "${DIR}/folderA" "${DIR}/folderB"
```